# ElasticSearchIntegrationTest : randomly occuring classpath error

Tags: elasticsearch

I just migrated some old test suite from using a local ElasticSearch cluster to extending ElasticSearchIntegrationTest (like described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html#integration-tests)).

```
@ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.ClusterScope(scope = ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.Scope.SUITE)
public class IndexingTestSuite extends ElasticsearchIntegrationTest{
    ...
}
```

When I launch it in IntelliJ, the following error occurs every other time.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: fix your classpath to have tests-framework.jar before lucene-core.jar
    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([D0FE9552B361A6B7]:0)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleSetupAndRestoreClassEnv.before(TestRuleSetupAndRestoreClassEnv.java:202)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleStoreClassName$1.evaluate(TestRuleStoreClassName.java:42)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.SystemPropertiesInvariantRule$1.evaluate(SystemPropertiesInvariantRule.java:55)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:39)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:39)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleAssertionsRequired$1.evaluate(TestRuleAssertionsRequired.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:48)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites.java:55)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:360)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The message is pretty clear about a classpath issue, but I've done nothing special. According to the documentation, I only added the following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
  <version>${lucene.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies were defined in the parent pom of my project.

The problem has been fixed by moving the `lucene-test-framework` dependency into each child pom (at first position).

see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch-fr/VcWFRq00oYQ).